# failed to create directory inside directory with sticky bit

Tags: permissions

I downloaded the android sdk `android-sdk_r24.3.4-linux.tgz` to /usr/src. And then I extracted it into /usr/local:

```
sudo tar xvzf android-sdk_r24.3.4-linux.tgz -C /usr/local
/usr/local$ ls
android-sdk-linux
```

I changed the group ownership of the tools directory and its file to a group my user belongs to (since the tools directory contains the android executable as well as others):

```
cd /usr/local/android-sdk-linux
sudo chown -R root:programmers tools
```

Now when I launch the android sdk manager and try to install libraries, I get an error like this:

```
Failed to create directory /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/temp
```

Ok, I want the sdk manager to create new files and directories but I do not want it to move existing files and directories (because when I changed to 777 permissions, some of the files were moved causing errors).

So I add the sticky bit:

```
sudo chmod +t android-sdk-linux
ls -ld android-sdk-linux
drwxrwxr-t 5 284663 5000 4096 Aug 14 18:38 android-sdk-linux
```

Yet even after I add the sticky bit, it produces the same error "Failed to create directory". Why is the sdk manager unable to create a directory inside the directory android-sdk-linux when said directory has the sticky bit?

Comment: which user did you launched the SDK? I can`t replicate what you having right now. I can create/remove file with same permission.

Comment: I just replicated it right now. I went inside android-sdk-linux and tried to create a directory and it did not let me::/usr/local/android-sdk-linux$ mkdir temp
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘temp’: Permission denied

Comment: i did the same, my user in the programmers group, same directory as you are. Im able to create the file from terminal using user in the programmers group. OK however you have small `T` which is sticky bit with executable permission. My one is capital `T` witout executable perm. Try to remove sticky bit and chmod to 774 then run the sticky bit again.

Comment: Why would I give other user read only?

Comment: 774 is readonly for others

Comment: Ok and why would a capital T work and a lower case t not work?

Comment: Because your ownership on `android-sdk-linux` is wrong. Thus write error. Do `chown root.programmers` on it.